# sprintf array of objects in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

With

```
$maids = getMaids();
```

I get `$maids` to be an array of PHP objects each one with the same structure. Is there any way I can sprintf the values inside of these objects with just two lines of code?

```
foreach($maids as &$maid)
    sprintf($form, $maid->name, $maid->pbx, $maid->id);
```

Why is the code above outputting nothing? Not even an error in the console.

I want to keep my code as clean as possible and using 3 lines just to assign the contents of the object to a variable and then `echo()` only that variable is too long. Why my shortcut is not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sprintf` doesn't output anything, it returns a string that you can then `echo` to output it; or try printf() instead

Comment: I've used sprintf in a mysqli fetch and it works just fine, outputting the values as I need. Will try printf in a second...

Comment: @Saturnix - perhaps you should inform PHP.net that their online docs are incorrect then - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: That must have been `printf` which produced output for you

Comment: Lol, that's what this answer suggested :)

Comment: exactly! Will mark as correct as soon as I can. Echo sprintf and printf both works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`printf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) instead of [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

`printf()` will output it's results to stdout while `sprintf()` will return the results as a string what is useful in some cases too